# Blog Post Image not showing when URL is shared

Tags: facebook, image, blogs, share, tumblr

I run a music website ([AlreadyHeard](http://AlreadyHeard.com/))
When we/user share links on Facebook, it very rarely shows the image used for that specific post.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? It would help improve our user experiece.

I currently have this in my site code:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="212601048836856" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="502049012" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Already Heard covers the latest news, interviews, features & reviews in rock, punk, hardcore, pop-punk, emo, indie & more. " /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="{Permalink}">
```

Comment: You seem to have missed the `og:image` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the proper Facebook Open Graph tags to give hints to the Facebook servers about what images/content/etc you want displayed when a link to your site is shared. The full documentation can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

The tag you want to use for images is `<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/images/picture.jpg"/>`. For a simpler guide on other tags you can use, check out: http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags